# How to use javafx SceneBuilder to achieve this style

Tags: javafx

First, there is such a 4x2 interface
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Psjgb.png)。

Then I clicked on the box in the upper left corner, it became like this
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKwgy.png)

It will look like this when I click on eight box.[image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRZfo.png)

I want to achieve this style, so I use SceneBuilder, Put the `ImageView` in the `Label`, but found that the `Label` has no click event to trigger。
(PS：All eight boxes can be clicked, and each click switches the state, which are shown and hidden respectively.)

Answer (score 1):

In Scenebuilder just use for `Label` the `on Mouse Clicked` field.

[image]